# Canvas relative mouse offsetting too far

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempt to detect mouse movement relative canvas. My canvas takes up 85% of the page and is fixed to the right hand side.

I have created a very basic example of my problem

My tick function runs in conjunction with requestAnimationFrame();

```
function requestNextFrame() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
}

function canvasTick() {
    var self = c;
    self.ctx.lineWidth="6";
    self.ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    self.ctx.rect(block.x, block.y, 20, 20);
    self.ctx.stroke();
    if(self.pauseTick) return requestNextFrame();
    if(typeof self.ctx !== 'undefined' && self.currImage !== null) {
        self.ctx.clearRect(0,0,self.canvasSize.width,self.canvasSize.height);
        self.ctx.drawImage(self.currImage, self.imagePos.x, self.imagePos.y, self.imageSize.right, self.imageSize.bottom);
    }
    requestNextFrame();
}
```

I have a mouseover event which listens for canvas mouseover events and then collects the mouse data using an object method called getMousePosition, thereafter setting the co-ordinates for the tick function to draw a square at the co-ordinates of the mouse.

```
self.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
    function(event) {
        self.mousePos = self.getMousePosition(event);
    },
false);
```

The mouse position method:

```
getMousePosition: function(event) {
    var self = this;
    var rect = self.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left);
    var mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top);
    return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
},
```

To see the code in action:

```js
function requestNextFrame() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
}

function canvasTick() {
 var self = c;
 self.ctx.lineWidth="2";
 self.ctx.strokeStyle="red";
 self.ctx.rect(block.x, block.y, 20, 20);
 self.ctx.stroke();
 requestNextFrame();
}

var block = {x:0, y:0};

var c = {
 canvas: null,
 ctx: null,
 currImage: null,
 isClicking: false,
 imagePos: {x:0, y:0},
 imageSize: {right:0, bottom:0},
 imageOffset: {left:-1, top:-1},
 mousePos: {x:0, y:0},
 pauseTick: true,
 canvasSize: {width:0, height:0},
  start: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.canvas = document.getElementById("imageViewer");
  self.ctx = self.canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  // Mouse movement detection
  self.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
   function(event) {
    self.mousePos = self.getMousePosition(event);
    block = self.mousePos;
   },
  false);
  
  self.canvasSize = {width:$(self.canvas).width(), height:$(self.canvas).height()};
  self.pauseTick = false;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
 },
  getMousePosition: function(event) {
  var self = this;
  var rect = self.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left);
  var mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top);
  return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
 },
  };
  
$(document).ready(function() {
 c.start();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="imageViewer" style="position: fixed; top:0; right:0; border: 1px solid #efefef; width: 85%; height: 100%;">
 
</canvas>
```

What is causing this bizarre offset to occur? I know it's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canvas has 2 sizes, the dimension of the pixels in the canvas (it's backingstore or drawingBuffer) and the display size. The number of pixels is set using the the canvas attributes. In HTML

```
<canvas width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Or in JavaScript

```
someCanvasElement.width = 400;
someCanvasElement.height = 300;
```

If you don't set the number of pixels it defaults to 300x150

Separate from that are the canvas's CSS style width and height

In CSS

```
canvas {  /* or some other selector */
   width: 500px;   // or any other unit like 50% or 15em or 100vw etc
   height: 400px;
}
```

Or in JavaScript

```
canvas.style.width = "500px";
canvas.style.height = "400px";
```

In your case you didn't set the number of pixels in the canvas so there are 300x150 pixels in the canvas. Those pixels are then stretched to 85% width and 100% height

To compute the correct mouse position for that situation change mouse code to

```
var mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left) * self.canvas.width / self.canvas.clientWidth | 0;
var mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top) * self.canvas.height / self.canvas.clientHeight | 0;
```

Here's a working version of your code with only that change

```js
function requestNextFrame() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
}

function canvasTick() {
 var self = c;
 self.ctx.lineWidth="2";
 self.ctx.strokeStyle="red";
 self.ctx.rect(block.x, block.y, 20, 20);
 self.ctx.stroke();
 requestNextFrame();
}

var block = {x:0, y:0};

var c = {
 canvas: null,
 ctx: null,
 currImage: null,
 isClicking: false,
 imagePos: {x:0, y:0},
 imageSize: {right:0, bottom:0},
 imageOffset: {left:-1, top:-1},
 mousePos: {x:0, y:0},
 pauseTick: true,
 canvasSize: {width:0, height:0},
  start: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.canvas = document.getElementById("imageViewer");
  self.ctx = self.canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  // Mouse movement detection
  self.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
   function(event) {
    self.mousePos = self.getMousePosition(event);
    block = self.mousePos;
   },
  false);
  
  self.canvasSize = {width:$(self.canvas).width(), height:$(self.canvas).height()};
  self.pauseTick = false;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
 },
  getMousePosition: function(event) {
  var self = this;
  var rect = self.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left) * self.canvas.width / self.canvas.clientWidth | 0;
  var mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top) * self.canvas.height / self.canvas.clientHeight | 0;
  return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
 },
  };
  
$(document).ready(function() {
 c.start();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="imageViewer" style="position: fixed; top:0; right:0; border: 1px solid #efefef; width: 85%; height: 100%;">
 
</canvas>
```

Most people want the canvas to have the same number of pixels as the size it's displayed. To do that use a small function like this

Most people want the canvas to have the same size as it's displayed. The easiest way to do that is with a small function

```
function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(canvas) {
   // look up the size the canvas is being displayed
   const width = canvas.clientWidth;
   const height = canvas.clientHeight;

   // If it's resolution does not match change it
   if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
     canvas.width = width;
     canvas.height = height;
     return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

```js
function requestNextFrame() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
}

function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(canvas) {
   // look up the size the canvas is being displayed
   const width = canvas.clientWidth;
   const height = canvas.clientHeight;

   // If it's resolution does not match change it
   if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
     canvas.width = width;
     canvas.height = height;
     return true;
   }

   return false;
}

function canvasTick() {
 var self = c;
  resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(self.ctx.canvas);
 self.ctx.lineWidth="2";
 self.ctx.strokeStyle="red";
 self.ctx.rect(block.x, block.y, 20, 20);
 self.ctx.stroke();
 requestNextFrame();
}

var block = {x:0, y:0};

var c = {
 canvas: null,
 ctx: null,
 currImage: null,
 isClicking: false,
 imagePos: {x:0, y:0},
 imageSize: {right:0, bottom:0},
 imageOffset: {left:-1, top:-1},
 mousePos: {x:0, y:0},
 pauseTick: true,
 canvasSize: {width:0, height:0},
  start: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.canvas = document.getElementById("imageViewer");
  self.ctx = self.canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  // Mouse movement detection
  self.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
   function(event) {
    self.mousePos = self.getMousePosition(event);
    block = self.mousePos;
   },
  false);
  
  self.canvasSize = {width:$(self.canvas).width(), height:$(self.canvas).height()};
  self.pauseTick = false;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(canvasTick);
 },
  getMousePosition: function(event) {
  var self = this;
  var rect = self.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left) * self.canvas.width / self.canvas.clientWidth | 0;
  var mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top) * self.canvas.height / self.canvas.clientHeight | 0;
  return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
 },
  };
  
$(document).ready(function() {
 c.start();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="imageViewer" style="position: fixed; top:0; right:0; border: 1px solid #efefef; width: 85%; height: 100%;">
 
</canvas>
```

Never use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` in your code. It's inflexible. Using the techniques above you can always just set the CSS to whatever you need and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The bizarre offsetting is occurring because, you set the canvas's width and height using css styles. You should either set it using canvas's native width and height property *(static)*

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="85" height="100"></canvas>
```

or *better*, set it dynamically *( using javascript )* ...

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 85 / 100;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

also, you should probably be using `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties to get the proper mouse coordinates within the canvas.

here's the [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/292c7qch/)

Comment: Brilliant,
Thank you!

Comment: Using percentages work just fine. [Using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight is an anti-pattern](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html).